# Adding markers dynamically to flutter google map

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-markers

I'm using Flutter to make a mobile application that uses a map. We decided to use Google map and the plugin for flutter we use is:

> google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.7

I understand that adding markers to the map works like this:

```
Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};
Marker _marker = new Marker(
  icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
  markerId: _markerId,
  position: LatLng(34.024441,-5.0310968),
  infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "userMarker", snippet: '*'),
);
GoogleMap _map;

@override
void initState(
   markers[_markerId] = _marker;
   _map = new GoogleMap(
    /* other properties irrelevant to this prob */
    markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers.values),
  );
);
```

The above snippet does work, I get to see the marker on the map. But modifying the marker or trying to add another marker like in the snippet below does not work.

```
FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        _marker = new Marker(
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
            markerId: _markerId,
            position: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
            infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "userMarker", snippet: '*'),
            onTap: () {
              debugPrint("Marker Tapped");
            },
          );
        markers[_markerId] = _marker; // What I do here is modify the only marker in the Map.
      });
      markers.forEach((id,marker) { // This is used to see if the marker properties did change, and they did.
        debugPrint("MarkerId: $id");
        debugPrint("Marker: [${marker.position.latitude},${marker.position.longitude}]");
      });
    });
)
```

My intention here is using another plugin (geoLocator) to get location data of the user and change the only marker I have so it can track his movements. The debugPrint shows that the data is indeed changing, but I see no change in the map (the initial marker that I change uses a different location than my own when I test).

Comment: You don't have _markers in the first code snippet, but you are using on the line of Set<Marker>.of(_markers.values), this made me think that your problem may be related to naming

Comment: I just mistakenly copied the wrong name. I'm actually passing the markers object to my custom map class constructor, which has the _markers property in it. Could it be a problem of referencing? Since I'm passing markers to a constructor and I don't know how Dart references objects.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If there's no specific reason for you to use Map data structure, here's what I've done in the past.

I have a `Set` of `Marker` in my `State`

```
Set<Marker> markers = Set();
```

Give it to the map widget. markers: markers

```
GoogleMap(
  onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
  myLocationEnabled: true,
  initialCameraPosition:
    CameraPosition(target: LatLng(0.0, 0.0)),
  markers: markers,
)
```

And then adding the Marker, which I'm building with search result and which you'll be building with your user's location, to Set of Marker in setState method.

```
// Create a new marker
Marker resultMarker = Marker(
  markerId: MarkerId(responseResult.name),
  infoWindow: InfoWindow(
  title: "${responseResult.name}",
  snippet: "${responseResult.types?.first}"),
  position: LatLng(responseResult.geometry.location.lat,
  responseResult.geometry.location.lng),
);
// Add it to Set
markers.add(resultMarker);
```

**Edit**: I've just noticed you're using GoogleMap widget in your `initState`, you need to move it to the `build` method if you want to rebuild it everytime with the new state values.

Comment: I'm using the map so I can keep track of the markerId. And your approach is exactly what I'm doing. It doesn't seem to be updating the map.

Comment: Yeah because GoogleMap is in your initState, not on the build method. Everytime the state changes, stateful widgets call their build method, not the initState method.

Comment: You're right, moving it to the build method works. But from what I understand, I need only one instance of GoogleMap, that's why I put it in the initState, moving it to the build method means every build will create a new instance. Is there a better approach?

Comment: It's the way to do in Flutter, React and React Native. Everytime your state changes, to reflect changes on the ui, framework schedules a build for necessary parts. Those frameworks are doing it efficiently, you don't have to worry about it. You are not gonna end up with hundred google map widgets and a slow app.