# How to remove all my markers and add new ones onPress?

Tags: flutter, google-maps-markers

I want to show trails markers and change to Events markers and back when pressing a button.
When i clear the markers, the size is 0, but they are not removed from the map.
So when i add the new ones, nothing happens.

**My initState**

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _listToMarkersTrails();
    isTrailsMode = true;
    message = "Go to Events";
}
```

**My map in a stack**

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      map,
      Positioned(top: 5, right: 5, child: _getButton())
    ],
  ),
```

**My _getbutton() method**

```
RaisedButton _getButton() {
    if (isTrailsMode) {
      return RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.green,
        onPressed: () => _changeMarkers(),
        child: Text("Change to Events"),
      );
    } else {
      return RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.blue,
        onPressed: () => _changeMarkers(),
        child: Text("Change to Trails"),
      );
    }
  }
```

**My _changeMarkers() method**

```
void _changeMarkers() {
    setState(() => map.markers.clear());
    if (isTrailsMode) _listToMarkersTrails();
    else _listToMarkersEvents();
    setState(() => isTrailsMode = !isTrailsMode);
  }
```

**My listToMarkers- methods**

```
void _listToMarkersTrails() {
  for (var i = 0; i < widget.trailList.length; i++) {
    setState(() {
  map.markers.add(Marker(
    icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(50.0),
    infoWindow: InfoWindow(
        title: widget.trailList[i].trailName,
        onTap: () => _navigateToTrail(widget.trailList[i])),
    markerId: MarkerId("id{$i}_trails"),
    position: widget.trailList[i].markers[0].position,
  ));
  });
}  
}

void _listToMarkersEvents() {
for (var i = 0; i < widget.eventList.length; i++) {
  setState(() {
    map.markers.add(Marker(
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(150.0),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: widget.eventList[i].date,
          onTap: () => _navigateToEvent(widget.eventList[i])),
      markerId: MarkerId("id{$i}_events"),
      position: widget.eventList[i].trail.markers[0].position,
    ));
  });
}
}
```

When i check the values, after a clear, markers.lenght = 0, but nothing is removed from the markers in the map.
What should I add? A controller?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**
I forgot to add, this is Flutter (dart).

Comment: You don't need a controller. GoogleMap package has changed, markers are widget now and GoogleMap widget takes Set of Markers in it's markers property. What you have to do is, have a Set of Markers in your state, give that Set to GoogleMap widget's markers property, and then call setState to mutate this Set. This will make the framework schedule a rebuild, so your GoogleMap will be build again with the new set of markers. Check my answer in this post to see code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55989289/9779791

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a controller. GoogleMap package has changed in version [0.3.0](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter#030), markers are widget now and GoogleMap widget takes Set of Markers in it's markers property.

What you have to do is, have a Set of Markers in your state, give that Set to GoogleMap widget's markers property, and then call setState to mutate this Set.

This will make the framework schedule a rebuild, so your GoogleMap will be build again with the new set of markers. Check my answer in this post to see code: [Adding markers dynamically to flutter google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987785/adding-markers-dynamically-to-flutter-google-map/55989289#55989289)

Note: I've posted my comment as an answer, according to this meta [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294792/9779791).

Answer (score 0):

Try this it can help you to solve your probleme,
I used it in my application of 'end of studies project' and it work.. good luck :)
I insert the data in firebase Realtime database inder the name of 'markers'.

AddMarker.dart

```
  List<MarkerData> markers = <MarkerData>[];

  void AddMarker() {
   DatabaseReference zoneRef =
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("markers");

    List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> zoneinfo = [];

    String key = zoneRef.push().key.toString();
     zoneRef.child(key).set({
      "latitude": _markerPosition.latitude.toString(),
      "longitude": _markerPosition.longitude.toString(),
     });
  }

  void updateMarker(Offset position) {
    _markerPosition = _controller.pixelToLatLng(position);

    AddMarker();

    int length = markers.length;
    if (length > 1) {
      markers[length - 1];
      _controller.insertMarker(markers.length - 1);
    }else {
       _controller.insertMarker(0);
     }
  }
```

markermodel.dart

```
     class MarkerData {
       String country;
       late String latitude;
       late String longitude;
       String adresse;
       String date;
       String time;

     MarkerData({
       required this.country,
       required this.adresse,
       required this.date,
       required this.latitude,
       required this.longitude,
       required this.time,
     });

     factory MarkerData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MarkerData(
       country: json["country"],
       adresse: json["adresse"],
       longitude: json["longitude"],
       latitude: json['latitude'],
       time: json['time'],
       date: json['date']);

     Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => ({
       "country": country,
       "adresse": adresse,
       "latitude": latitude,
       "longitude": longitude,
       "date": date,
       "time": time,
     });
    }

     List<MarkerData> _markers = [];
```

nb: if my code help you thanks to like my post or show this links

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/13025/how-to-update-the-markers-dynamically-using-flutter-maps
and https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/166687/add-a-marker-dynamically-by-clicking-on-the-map