# How Can I Add Ads Into A Flutter Google Maps Application?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, admob, ads

I have a location sharing app. Is there a way to easily add sponsored markers (without directly asking for sponsorships and placing markers) on a flutter Google Map, kinda like Waze does? Does AdMob have an api I can use? Thanks. [image: Waze ad]

Comment: You can create a [custom set of markers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55989289/2516576) for any map rendition.

Comment: @JesseLawson, I'm aware of that. But getting actual ads for a given location area is what I really need.